# how to sync two rocketmq cluster which are in different networks

Tags: rocketmq

I got rocketmq clusters named A and B, they are in network net-A and net-B separately. How could I sync their **topics and messages.**

Comment: I've tried rocketmq-replicator, and it doesn't work so well, always **NoClassDefFoundError**, or maybe can somebody tell me how to solve this problem?

Answer (score 0):

You should define them in the same broker groups, say master is in net-A and slave is in net-B.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for your attention to RocketMQ.

Sorry for your inconvenience. We are still working on the replicator of RocketMQ. The improvement would be released soon in the next few versions.

At the moment, we recommend you make them a master-slave mode and define them in the same broker group. This enables the slave node to sync its topics and messages with the master node.